# get original creation date of html file

Tags: files, timestamps, download, http, stat

Can I find the creation/last modified date of an html file? For example, I would like to know when some index.html file from some website was created, not when I downloaded it.

Comment: For static HTML pages backed by files, the `Last-Modified` header in the HTTP response usually reflects the last modification time.

Comment: For UNIX/Linux creation date is not part of the file definition

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers don't do anything special to set the time stamp on a downloaded file, so the file ends up being dated from the download. Download managers usually change the downloaded file's modification time to match the [`Last-Modified` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Response_fields) sent by the server. With command line tools, use `wget` or `curl -R` to set the file's modification time to the time sent by the server (and `wget --no-use-server-timestamps` or `curl` to set it to the download time).

The server will generally set the `Last-Modified` header to the time the file was last modified, if the content of the URL is stored as a file. In these days of dynamically-generated content, that's not so common anymore. There's no way to get the creation date; most filesystems don't even record it.